# C# - Events and delegates when receiving data

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates, async-await

I want to display a string when I receive data from a server. For that I was thinking on using delegates and events. I'm new to this topic (Delegates and Events) so I'm have not been able to set this up.
Here is what I've done:

```
public delegate void ClientHandleData(byte[] data, int bytesRead);
public event ClientHandleData OnDataReceived;

public void ConnectToServer(string ipAddress, int port)
{
    this.port = port;
    tcpClient = new TcpClient(ipAddress, port);
    clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForData));
    started = true;
    t.Start();
}
private void ListenForData()
{
   int bytesRead;

   while (started)
   {
      bytesRead = 0;

      try
      {
          bytesRead = clientStream.Read(buffer.ReadBuffer, 0, readBufferSize);      
      }
      catch
      {
        //A socket error has occurred
        MessageBox.Show("A socket error has occurred);
        break;
      }

      if (OnDataReceived != null)
      {

                // display string to a textbox on the UI
      }

    Thread.Sleep(15);
   }

   started = false;

   Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Listening on a separate thread is not a good idea any more, its preferred to use `Async-Await` to asynchronously get the data and update the Ui in continuation,w hich runs on the main / caller thread

Comment: Check my answer related to converting the complete code into `Async - Await` and listen to the server in the non blocking manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write

```
OnDataReceived?.Invoke(buffer.ReadBuffer, bytesRead);
```

If you want to be sure that your event will not be set to `null` after the `if` statement you can do this:

```
var handler = OnDataReceived;
handler?.Invoke(buffer.ReadBuffer, bytesRead);
```

Be careful when updating UI, because you can only update UI from UI thread. If you are using WPF you can do this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
   // Update your UI.
});
```

And also make sure that someone actually subscribed to the event:

```
public void Foo()
{
    objectWithTheEvent.OnDataReceived += OnOnDataReceived;
}

private void OnOnDataReceived(byte[] data, int count)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us have a look at your TcpClient listening code. When you call `stream.Read()` you can not be sure how much data will be read from your socket so you have to read until the end of the stream or you have to know how much date you are supposed to read from socket. Let us assume that you know how much data you are supposed to read

```
var readSofar = 0;
var iNeedToRead = 500;//500Bytes
try{
    while(readSoFar<iNeedToRead){
       var readFromSocket = clientStream.Read(buffer.ReadBuffer, readSofar, readBufferSize-readSofar);
       if(readFromSocket==0){
         //Remote server ended your connection or timed out etc
         //Do your error handling may be stop reading
       } 
       readSofar += readFromSocket;
    }

    }
     catch {
       //A socket error has occurred
       MessageBox.Show("A socket error has occurred);
       break;
     }
 if (OnDataReceived != null){
    // display string to a textbox on the UI
 }
```

You can use null propogation operator like this.

```
OnDataReceived?.Invoke(buffer.ReadBuffer, bytesRead);
```

If you are using WindowsForm each controller has to be updated from UI thread therefore you have to call from the subscriber method

```
private void IReceivedData(byte[] data, int count){
    this.Invoke(()=>{...Your code});
}
```